# Smoothness of composition of possibly non-smooth functions

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-functions, diffeomorphism

For $s>0$, define $F_s:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$, $x\mapsto |x|^{s-1}x$ which is a homeomorphism and a diffeomorphism if and only if $s=1$. Now for $s,t>0$ with $s\neq t$ and $s,t\neq 1$, I would like to show that at least one of $F_t\circ F_s^{-1}$ or $F_s\circ F_t^{-1}$ is not smooth (here smooth means $C^\infty$). I realize that this should be fairly straight forward, but I am not sure how to come up with a short proof/explanation for it. I thought of trying to find $F_s^{-1}$ explicitly but I am wondering if there is some straight-forward way of showing this.

For background, I am trying to prove that a collection of smooth structures are not compatible (differential geometry).

Comment: If $0<s<1$, are you working on $\Bbb R^n-\{0\}$?

Comment: It's easy enough to write down the inverse function: $F_s^{-1}(y) = |y|^{\frac 1s-1}y$. (As with my earlier comment, we'd better have $1/s\ge 1$ for this even to make sense at $y=0$.) So we cannot have both $s\ge 1$ and $1/s\ge 1$ unless $s=1$. Do you mean differentiable rather than smooth? Unless $s-1$ is an even integer, $F_s$ won't be smooth at $0$. And I guess $F_s^{-1}$ won't be smooth unless $1/s - 1$ is an even integer.

Comment: Thank you for the comments...I actually figured this out earlier today. I was having trouble writing down the inverse but eventually got it. Interestingly, this actually defines a group homomorphism from $\mathbb{R}^+$ to functions on $\mathbb{R}^n$ defined by the map $s\mapsto F_s$